# Separate string every 3 characters and putting them in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

The result I want is:

```
x = "whateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever"
...
y = ['wha', 'tev', ..., 'ver']
```

I want to do this without iterating through the entire string,
because I need to do this in extremely large strings with thousands of
characters. Needs to be as quick as possible.

Comment: Welcome to SO! We help you with programming questions, not take requirements and code them for you! Why don't you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Since when is thousands of characters extremely large?

Comment: What I've tried so far, which has worked, though not as quickly as I'd like is iterating through the string character by character, using an integer to count to 3, every iteration it adds the part of the string it's iterating through to a substring for temporary storage. When the integer used to count reaches 3, it adds the temporary storage substring to a list, then defines the temporary storage substring as "" again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although separating the string does not take much time, but Anyway, do:

```
x = "whateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever"
y = [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)]
print(y)
```

output:

```
['wha', 'tev', 'erw', 'hat', 'eve', 'rwh', 'ate', 'ver', 'wha', 'tev', 'erw', 'hat', 'eve', 'rwh', 'ate', 'ver']
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, that's exactly what I needed. Cheers.